# Setting a variable for dataString

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I am creating a user comment system. Right now I am attempting to `SELECT` a user's last comment and then automatically get the new comment with AJAX.

I am getting an error that `dataString` is not defined. I do not know how to define this within my php. Since I am echoing out all of this:

```
echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                echo $commenter_img;
                echo '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                echo '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                echo '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
```

Do I just set all of this to dataString or how else do I do it?

Full code:

This is my form and `SELECT` query on the comment page. This way the results will load on page load.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment-form">
            <textarea id="home_comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." maxlength="1000" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <input id="comment-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
        <div id="comment-container">
<?php
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
";

  if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date, $commenter_user_id, $commenter_img);
    //var_dump($select_comments_stmt);  
        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_img;
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                echo $commenter_img;
                echo '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                echo '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                echo '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
  }
```

AJAX file

```
function commentRetrieve(){

        $.ajax({ 
                url: "ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php",
                type: "get",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {
                //  console.log(data);
                    if (data == "Error!") {
                        alert("Unable to retrieve comment!");
                        alert(data);
                    } else {
                        $('#comment-container').prepend(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                    console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                }
            });


    }
    setInterval(commentRetrieve, 300);
```

PHP file

```
$user = new User();

function selectNewComment() {

//Get the last insert id
    $select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    WHERE c.id=$last_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
";

  if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date, $commenter_user_id, $commenter_img);    
        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_img;
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                echo $commenter_img;
                echo '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                echo '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                echo '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
}   

selectNewComment();
```

$con variable error:

my init file:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$usernameCon = 'actual';
$passwordCon = 'actual';

try {   
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname=actual', $usernameCon, $passwordCon);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
```

Comment: What should be the `dataString`?  What query string are you trying to pass to the server? I can't see any `$_GET` in your PHP

Comment: I am trying to get information from the server to my php file to AJAX to the DOM. I want to return all of the echo'd out pieces of information in my php file to my AJAX within dataString.

Comment: `dataString` is the query string that you're sending **to** PHP file

Comment: Oh, well I must have typed it wrong. How can I pass the echoed information from php into the ajax?

Comment: You're doing it good. Just define `dataString` so that your code don't throw any errors. You can even remove `data: dataString,` from your code if you're not sending anything to the PHP file...

Comment: Why would I send data to the php file, when all I need to do is get the information from the php file? I have another file in which I `INSERT` the comment... for this all I need to do is get the information.

Comment: Yes! As I wrote in previous comment - *You can even remove `data: dataString`, from your code if you're not sending anything to the PHP file...*

Comment: It is throwing an error for `$last_id` . It doesn't on my comment page? Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

You got this error, because the javascript variable dataString is not defined :)

How did you call the javascript function ? Do you need to specity any data when you call the page via ajax ?

A solution - specify the ID (for example)

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php',
  type: 'get',
  data: {id: 36}, // for example, id #36. You can retrieve this data on your PHP page via $_GET['id']
  success: function (data) {
    /* [...] rest of your code */
  }
});
```

Another solution - remove the data/dataString

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php',
  type: 'get',
  success: function (data) {
    /* [...] rest of your code */
  }
});
```

I.E.: I see a `$last_id` varaible in your `$select_comments_sql`. I think there is another issue :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct `$last_id` is throwing an error. It doesn't on my comment page? Not sure why?

Comment: What is the source of this value ? The ID of the comment ?

If yes, use a: `selectNewComment($_GET['id']);` (check if the variable exists, and protect from any attacks)
and: `function selectNewComment($last_id) { ... }`

and on the ajax call add `data: {id: 36}`
Of course, you will have to fill automatically if id (here #36) by a php code or javascript

Comment: The reason of the error is because the variable is not defined.
Morevoer inside a function you can't use external variables (some exceptions as $_GET/POST/REQUEST/COOKIES/ENV/SESSION).

Comment: Nevermind, the $last_id code was old. I have changed my select query, but now it is throwing an error for my $con variable.. (my connection). I have my connection in my init file, which I call for right after the error calling code. I just posted my $con in my question. Why would this be throwing an error for it?

Comment: Olivares It gives a `notice: undefined variable con` and `Fatal Error: call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`.

Comment: Same issue as previously :) Variable is not defined **inside the function** (variable is defined, before but **outside**)
Line in error is `if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {`. Give the $con variable as parameter of your function : `selectNewComment($con, $_GET['id']);` and `function selectNewComment($con, $last_id) { ... }`

Comment: Olivares Thanks. I just removed the function. Now it is giving a fatal error. Saying: Fatal Error: call to undefined method pdo::bind_result()

Comment: Bind_result ? Hum ... what is it ?  `bindParam` no ? or function `execute` directly ? Moreover, you will have another errors: all you variables $comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date, $commenter_user_id, $commenter_img are not defined PLUS are not used on your query.
(read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php :))

Comment: I thought the bind_result was where I put variables, in order of what was being selected?

Comment: Yes, the logic is correct. But `bind_result` does not exists on PDO (i.e.: `bindParam` or in your case `execute` is the equivalent) ; neither your variables. Check **PDO** courses/tutoriel and *how to get variables from POST/GET* :)